# Intuition behind proof of Schwarz's lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition

There is the very well known proof of [Schwarz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) in complex analysis. When I read it I feel like the answers described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130883/are-there-proofs-that-you-feel-you-did-not-understand-for-a-long-time). I'm not sure how I would motivate and explain why one should expect the proof to work when talking to someone new to complex analysis despite the proof to be relatively short.

We are given $f$ is a holomorphic map such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)| \le 1$ on $D$. I never understood why there wasn't someway to take this and look at $$f(z) = a_1z+a_2z^2 +\cdots$$ where the $a_i$ are constrained because of $|f(z)|\le 1$ in such a way that one can conclude that $|f(z)\le |z|$ and $f'(0)\le 1$. Why can't such an approach work?

Comment: So you would assume $a_1>1$. Then for $|f(z)|\le1$ for $z\approx 1$, some other $a_k$ must counteract for positive reals. But then for some other angle $a_1z$ and $a_kz^k$ overlay construtively instead, so there must be more counteraction by other powers etc. The fact that all such attempts is precisely the maximum modulus principle used in the usual proof, and hard to capture directlyusing power series.

Comment: Building on what Hagen von Eitzen said, it is not that there is *not* a way to do it via power series (technically everything could be worded in terms of power series in some way if you really desired) but that the maximum modulus principle is itself really important and fairly intuitive; importantly, the key behind extending this result to the Riemann Mapping Theorem and further to the Uniformization Conjecture is in the study of conformal mappings. The geometry of holomorphic functions can be quite insightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schwarz lemma is a profound result of non-euclidean geometry as it says that conformal maps that preserve the unit disc decrease hyperbolic distance on the unit disc; there is a book by S. Dineen called precisely that ([The Schwarz Lemma](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486801209), Clarendon Press, 1989, reprinted in an inexpensive pb by Dover Press) that goes into its many facets and extensions.

The results you want about Taylor Coefficients of functions that satisfy it (or more generally bounded analytic functions on the disc) are known collectively as Schur's theorem with extensions by Caratheodory, Pick, Nevanlinna and are fairly unuseful directly and more important theoretically (as they are expressed in terms of positivity of quadratic forms of arbitrary number of variables and similar such inequalities, or in terms of shift/multiplication operators on Hardy Spaces in more abstract terms). Their abstract characterization implies fairly easily the classical Schwarz Lemma, though it feels kind of like going backward

Comment: Where can I find an exposition on this Schur's theorem?

Comment: A 2 page modern proof with references is in the ams proceedings 2001/11  https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-11/home.html   https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-11/S0002-9939-01-06199-8/S0002-9939-01-06199-8.pdf

Comment: Wait how can Schur's theorem be used to prove Schwarz's lemma

Comment: If $a_0=0$ then show the shifted coefficients to the left ($\frac{f(z)}{z}$ Taylor coefficients) also satisfy the assumptions of Schur, so $|\frac{f(z)}{z}| \le 1$